# R XML package does not load

Tags: xml, r

I want to instal the R XML package

```
> install.packages("XML")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Marc/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/XML_3.98    -1.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4296516 bytes (4.1 MB)
downloaded 4.1 MB

package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘XML’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGMYM8a\downloaded_packages
```

When I try to open it I get an error however...Any more people who have experienced this? And fix for this? Or an alternative XML package?

> library(XML)
>   Error in library(XML) : there is no package called ‘XML’

Comment: Go to your installation folder (usually in documents\R...), manually delete the XML directory and re-install.

Comment: Had already tried it, but trying another time worked:). Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I find that the above always works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Was some previous version of the XML package active in your R session before trying to install the package? Also, do you have the latest R version?

2) Have you tried manually copying the "XML" directory (folder) 
from: C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGMYM8a\downloaded_packages
to: C:/Users/Marc/Documents/R/win-library/3.2
/where all your R packages are stored/